# How to see how many FPS can a video card render and Benchmark video card

Tags: graphics, benchmarks

Am looking for ways to benchmark how many FPS can a video card render. For the moment I only know about `glxgears` which comes with the package `mesa-utils`:

[image]

What other tools can I use to benchmark or see how many FPS can a video card render.

NOTE - In the example about `glxgears` I know is as simple as a directx rendering. Is not a benchmark but I am showing it to give an idea of what kind of tool am looking for. Something similar to 3dmark. Also I know as mentioned in other places that `glxgears` can no be used as a benchmark tool, specially since it varies greatly depending on how big the gear window is and if it has another window on top of it. So not very precise. Apart from that what programs in Ubuntu can I use to see FPS and do benchmarks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Globs ap

Installation - Found in Software Center

Simple benchmark program that has multiple opengl tests and shows best, average and worst FPS for each test.

[image]

## Phoronix Test Suite

Installation - Found in Software Center

Extensive Benchmark Utility. Includes several modules for Graphics to test out several Graphic technologies (Not just simple FPS counts).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The number of frames a second your card can render will vary wildly depending on the amount of detail in each frame.  For example, most cards can render `glxgears` very quickly due to the simple geometry and lack of textures, but would have difficulty matching that rate for more complex real-world scenes.

Many games have some way to report their frame rate, so that might be a better test.